# Solving BCD using 10s complement

Tags: binary, computer-arithmetic

25-7 is the question.
(0010 0101 - 0111).
Change 0111 to 0011 (using 10s complement) and add it, isn't it?
I've been trying to solve using 10s complement but couldn't.
Please help me solve the question by using 10s complement.
Thank you.